# acer aspire 5737z memory card reader not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: card-reader

My laptop is Acer Aspire 5737z and my memory card reader is not working (it is not recognized). Can I get some help?
Thank you,
Vali.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility that the drivers for the Card reader are missing (Assuming its built in). Try the command `lspci`in the terminal and check whether the driver is installed. You can also check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492476/internal-sd-card-reader-not-mounted-detected-hp-realtek-rts5227) for reference.

Comment: I think also the drivers are faulty or missing. So I made a little research and I found that my built-in Card reader was manufactured by jMikron, and its name is JMB380. I wrote an email to jMikron and asked for the drivers for my OS and lalptop model. I waited a few days and still got no answers from them. I think I will give up, maybe in the next version of Ubuntu some drivers will be included for this type of Card reader.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the exfat drivers

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```