# Realtek RTS5227 Card Reader Problems

Tags: drivers, 15.10, realtek, sd-card

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, and it doesn't detect my SD card insertions. I've tried multiple solutions that seem to be the common answer for a problem like this, but no success.

I saw [this discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492476/internal-sd-card-reader-not-mounted-detected-hp-realtek-rts5227) that indicated that there's a driver by Realtek for a similar device, and that some minor hacks usually solve the problem for my specific device.

After following those steps and running `make`, I get the following errors:

```
cp -f ./define.release ./define.h
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/build/ SUBDIRS=/home/anti/Software/rts5227 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.o
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c: In function ‘proc_info’:
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:148:55: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  SPRINTF("        Build: %s, %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                       ^
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:148:55: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
In file included from include/linux/printk.h:6:0,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:13,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:17,
                 from include/linux/blkdev.h:4,
                 from /home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:23:
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c: In function ‘rtsx_control_thread’:
include/linux/kern_levels.h:4:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘u64 {aka long long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
 #define KERN_SOH "\001"  /* ASCII Start Of Header */
                  ^
include/linux/kern_levels.h:10:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘KERN_SOH’
 #define KERN_ERR KERN_SOH "3" /* error conditions */
                  ^
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:521:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘KERN_ERR’
    printk(KERN_ERR "Bad target number (%d:%d)\n",
           ^
include/linux/kern_levels.h:4:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘u64 {aka long long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
 #define KERN_SOH "\001"  /* ASCII Start Of Header */
                  ^
include/linux/kern_levels.h:10:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘KERN_SOH’
 #define KERN_ERR KERN_SOH "3" /* error conditions */
                  ^
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:527:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘KERN_ERR’
    printk(KERN_ERR "Bad LUN (%d:%d)\n",
           ^
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c: In function ‘rtsx_probe’:
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:921:39: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  printk(KERN_INFO "--- %s, %s ---\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                       ^
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:921:49: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  printk(KERN_INFO "--- %s, %s ---\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                 ^
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c: At top level:
/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.c:132:12: warning: ‘proc_info’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int proc_info (struct Scsi_Host *host, char *buffer,
            ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/anti/Software/rts5227/rtsx.o] Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/anti/Software/rts5227' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/anti/Software/rts5227] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic'
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Is there any way I can solve this and use this driver to use my reader?

My kernel version is `4.2.0-34-generic`.

This is the output for `lspci -v | grep Reader`

```
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I'll provide any other output that might be needed to solve the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

The thing causing problems is the implicit declaration of the function `vmalloc()` throughout the various files of the driver's source.

I added `#include <linux/vmalloc.h>` to the relevant files, which are `rtsx.c`, `rtsx_chip.c`, `rtsx_scsi.c` and `ms.c`.

I still got a lot of warnings and notes when running make, but was able to compile and install the driver, and the SD cards work now!