# How do I mount SD Card to Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP Envy 13t?

Tags: sd-card

The card slot works fine on windows. `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't show any SD card. I checked by giving the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and inserting SD card again, nothing happened.
Output from lspci(relevant bit):

```
    01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro Device 6625,
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 83a7,
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Output from lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5ed Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Do you see a card reader from the command `lsusb`?

Comment: @KristopherIves , This is what I see, couldn't figure out what is Device 002 ..........


>Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

>Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp

>Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5ed Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd

>Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Add the output from `lsusb` to you original question, it is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @MatsK done.  Sorry for the issue!

Comment: Okay so I don't see a card reader in the `lsusb` output, whereas most of the time I usually see something like `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller` when a reader is recognized by Linux.

Comment: Looking on HP's website it does appear it's likely a Realtek card reader as well, which lead me to find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492476/internal-sd-card-reader-not-mounted-detected-hp-realtek-rts5227) that may help you. You might not have the same card reader as that guy, but my guess is you can use the same overall strategy to get your card reader working. You may have to get the name of the card reader using `sudo lshw` or similar.

Comment: For completeness' sake: the `Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd ` device is probably your webcam.

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2` . Ref.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/787088/ubuntu-16-04-does-not-detect-sd-card-reader

Comment: @MatsK that doesnt seem to work

Comment: @KristopherIves just checked with 'lspci -v', updated the question, its an alcor micro device, I'm looking for drivers and will update this section if I find any.

Comment: seems like there's no device driver available for Alcor micro device 6625